# DevCon - отключение устройства

Tags: windows, администрирование

Есть устройство - в данном случае usb гарнитура

У неё через диспетчер задач можно по отдельности отключать динамики и микрофон.

Но у них один и тот же `ИД Оборудования`

Как можно отключить устройство например не по `ИД` так как оно у них одинаковое, а по другим свойствам оборудования с помощью `DevCon` ?

Answer (score 1):

Devcon позволяет отключать устройство по Device Instance ID (пути к экземпляру устройства), который уникален для каждого устройства в системе:

```
devcon disable "@USB\VID_1E3D&PID_2096\ABCD12345678"
```

Подробнее: [DevCon Disable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-disable)